# Is there a neater, more elegant way to format this output?

Tags: c++, formatting

I have this code that writes the initial configuration of a simulator I'm writing to `stdout`. `args` is an instance of type `struct Arguments`, and all the members of said struct are used in the singular function below. I was hoping for some hints to simplify the code and get the alignment correct.

I have considered using `<cstdio>` and simply writing the output I need to a buffer string with `sprintf` (this code is *guaranteed* to be shorter) and then writing to the console with either `std::cout` or `printf`. However, I have tried my best to avoid using any C libraries in this project.

```
struct Arguments {
    std::string_view protocol{"MESI"};
    std::filesystem::path benchmark{"data/bodytrack"};
    uint32_t cacheSize{4096};
    uint8_t associativity{2};
    uint16_t blockSize{32};
    uint32_t numBlocks{4096 / 32};

    Arguments() = default;
    explicit Arguments(const char* argv[]);
  };

void Runner::printConfig() const {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "====================================" << std::endl
     << "Cache protocol:\t\t" << args.protocol << std::endl
     << "Cache size:\t\t" << args.cacheSize << " B";

  if (args.cacheSize > (1 << 10) && args.cacheSize < (1 << 20))
    ss << " (" << std::setprecision(4) << static_cast<double>(args.cacheSize) / static_cast<double>(1 << 10) << " KiB)"
       << std::endl;
  else if (args.cacheSize > (1 << 20))
    ss << " (" << std::setprecision(4) << static_cast<double>(args.cacheSize) / static_cast<double>(1 << 20) << " MiB)"
       << std::endl;
  else ss << std::endl;

  ss << "Block size:\t\t" << args.blockSize << " B" << std::endl;

  ss << "Associativity:\t\t";
  if (args.associativity == 1) ss << "direct-mapped" << std::endl;
  else if (args.associativity == args.numBlocks) ss << "fully associative" << std::endl;
  else {
    ss << std::to_string(args.associativity) << "-way set-associative" << std::endl
       << "Cache blocks:\t\t" << args.numBlocks << " (" << (args.numBlocks / args.associativity) << " per set)"
       << std::endl
       << "====================================";
    std::cout << ss.view() << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  ss << "Cache blocks:\t\t" << args.numBlocks << std::endl << "====================================";

  std::cout << ss.view() << std::endl;
}
```

Run with the arguments `Dragon bodytrack 1024 2 16`, this outputs:

```
====================================
Cache protocol:     Dragon
Cache size:     1024 B (1 KiB)
Block size:     16 B
Associativity:      2-way set-associative
Cache blocks:       4 (2 per set)
====================================
```

**N.B.**

1. I'm aware that the separators are not long enough: that's also in the pipeline).
2. I wish I could use `<format>`, but this project is cross-platform and only MSVC has implemented it at all.
3. Ideally no large third-party libraries (Boost, etc).

Comment: You're missing the definition of `args`.  Without that, it's very hard to review this code.

Comment: Have a look at fmt - https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), especially in picking a title for your question.

Comment: There are several C++ formatting libraries out there. [Boost Format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) I even wrote one [ThorIOUtil](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsIOUtil/tree/042e5f73935c91d38b9df94488b00fd00e2b2be2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't use `std::endl` unless you actually need flushing behavior. For a newline, just output `"\n"`.
- Use the manipulators from [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) to get fixed column sizes. Specifically `std::setw(n)` to set the output width to size `n`, and `std::left` or `std::right` align things if necessary.
- Consider sticking to one line of output per `ss << ...` chain (except where it's necessary to break a line up).
- As mentioned by upkajdt in the comments, you could use [`fmtlib`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) where `std::format` isn't implemented yet. (The two should be functionally equivalent, so you could use a wrapper function to forward calls to the appropriate backend).

---

```
  if (args.cacheSize > (1 << 10) && args.cacheSize < (1 << 20))
    ss << " (" << std::setprecision(4) << static_cast<double>(args.cacheSize) / static_cast<double>(1 << 10) << " KiB)"
       << std::endl;
  else if (args.cacheSize > (1 << 20))
    ss << " (" << std::setprecision(4) << static_cast<double>(args.cacheSize) / static_cast<double>(1 << 20) << " MiB)"
       << std::endl;
  else ss << std::endl;
```

We can simplify this slightly by checking for the largest size first, and moving the newline out of the condition:

```
if (args.cacheSize > (1 << 20))
    ss << " (" << std::setprecision(4) << static_cast<double>(args.cacheSize) / static_cast<double>(1 << 20) << " MiB)";
else if (args.cacheSize > (1 << 10))
    ss << " (" << std::setprecision(4) << static_cast<double>(args.cacheSize) / static_cast<double>(1 << 10) << " KiB)";

ss << "\n";
```

Converting to KiB / MiB could perhaps be done in a separate function.

---

```
  ss << "Associativity:\t\t";
  if (args.associativity == 1) ss << "direct-mapped" << std::endl;
  else if (args.associativity == args.numBlocks) ss << "fully associative" << std::endl;
  else {
    ss << std::to_string(args.associativity) << "-way set-associative" << std::endl
       << "Cache blocks:\t\t" << args.numBlocks << " (" << (args.numBlocks / args.associativity) << " per set)"
       << std::endl
       << "====================================";
    std::cout << ss.view() << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  ss << "Cache blocks:\t\t" << args.numBlocks << std::endl << "====================================";

  std::cout << ss.view() << std::endl;
```

Is it really necessary to conditionally output the blocks?

```
ss << std::setw(20) << "Associativity:";

if (args.associativity == 1) ss << "direct-mapped";
else if (args.associativity == args.numBlocks) ss << "fully associative";
else ss << std::to_string(args.associativity) << "-way set-associative";

ss << "\n";

ss << std::setw(20) << "Cache blocks:" << args.numBlocks << " (" << (args.numBlocks / args.associativity) << " per set)" << "\n";
ss << "====================================";

std::cout << ss.view() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper function:

```
void print_KorM (std::ostream& o, double val)
{
    o.precision(4);
    constexpr double K = 1.0 << 10;
    constexpr double M = 1.0 << 20;
    if (val > M)  o << (val/M) << "MiB";
    else if (val > K)  o << (val/K) << "KiB";
    else o << val;
}
```

Note that there is **no casting** needed in the implementation or by the caller.

In general, break out all the complicated *format it this way or that way depending on the range or other values* into their own functions, even if they are only used once.  Then your principal function is just outputting captions and a simple statement for each value.  (e.g. `numBlocks`)

---

You write: `ss << std::to_string(args.associativity)`
This is inefficient as you create a string object, rather than formatting directly into the stream.  I'm guessing you do this because writing `ss << args.associativity` directly formats it as a character rather than an integer?  The simple, zero-overhead fix for that is to write: `ss << 0+args.associativity`.

You could write `int(args.associativity)` but this begs the question of what is the proper type to use actually.  By using `0+` it will invoke the promotion rules to give a type that we know is *at least* an `int` (since the literal `0` is of type `int`) thus not a char-sized type that causes issues.  It will also continue to work unchanged if you ever change the definition of `associativity` to a different type, such as `uint32_t`, as the arithmetic promotion rules will cover that.